Converting terminal compilation into a latex-workshop recipe
I'm kind of new to using the extension of latex-worshop (I used to compile the documents with the terminal) and I want to start using it to have some order with the different variety of documents I work with. Does anyone knows how to make this into a recipe?
I'm using the Kaobook template
pdflatex main # Compile template
makeindex main.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o main.nls # Compile nomenclature
makeindex main # Compile index
biber main # Compile bibliography
pdflatex main # Compile template
makeglossaries main # Compile glossary
pdflatex main # Compile template

Here is what I have set so far:
{"latex-workshop.latex.recipes": [
        {
            "name": "Kaobook",
            "tools": [
                "pdflatex",
                "makeindex-nomenclature",
                "makeindex-index",
                "biber",
                "pdflatex",
                "makeglossaries",
                "pdflatex"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "latex-workshop.latex.tools": [
        {
            "name": "pdflatex",
            "command": "pdflatex",
            "args": [
                "-synctex=1",
                "-interaction=nonstopmode",
                "-file-line-error",
                "%DOC%"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "makeindex-nomenclature",
            "command": "makeindex",
            "args": [
                "%DOCFILE%.nlo",
                "-s",
                "nomencl.ist",
                "-o",
                "%DOCFILE%.nls"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "makeindex-index",
            "command": "makeindex",
            "args": [
                "%DOCFILE%"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "biber",
            "command": "biber",
            "args": [
                "%DOCFILE%"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "makeglossaries",
            "command": "makeglossaries main",
            "args": [
                "%DOCFILE%"
            ]
        }
    ]}

Thanks for reading

Note that you are probably much better of using latexmk -pdf, it will autoimatically detect the need for biber and makeindex runs. And can be configured for makeglossaries as well. It is the tool that overleaf (and my self) uses behind the scenes.
